# Applying XSLT to XML in a JSP page

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, jstl, server-side

what I'm trying to do is stylise XML output in my JSP page through XSLT.

But I want to Import my xml file run a < x:forEach select to display all my content and then stylise the content with my XSLT file

Here is my current code

```
<c:import var="articleinfo" url="/WEB-INF/articles.xml" />  
<x:parse xml="${articleinfo}" var="output"/>
<c:set var="xmltext">
<x:forEach select="$output/articles/article" var="story">
<x:out select="$story" />
</x:forEach>
</c:set>
<c:import url="authors.xsl" var="xslt"/>
<x:transform xml="${xmltext}" xslt="${xslt}"/>
```

Now without the c:set and the x:transform the XML is outputted as one continues line of text, which tells me that the x:forEach works but now that I want to stylise it with XSLT I get an error:

"HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Premature end of file."

What is it that I should be looking at to properly code in my XSLT?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just figured out what is happening, it was one of those oh my its right in front of me moments... :|

Heres my answer to my question.

```
<c:import url="articles.xsl" var="xslt"/>
<c:import url="/WEB-INF/articles.xml" var="articles"/>
<x:transform xml="${articles}" xslt="${xslt}"/>
```

I wasn't properly importing my xml properly and applying various statements that need not be there.

All displaying correctly now :D